# JMETER JMS Publisher

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I would like to push messages on to MQ with 800 TPS rate using JMS Publisher in JMETER. Please advice the right approach. I am trying to use constant throughput but I am unable to achieve it.
I am giving like 60*800=48000 within constant throughput timer. But not been able to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

With how many threads (virtual users) defined in [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)? 1?

1. First of all try increasing the number of threads
2. Constant Throughput Timer can only **pause** the requests to **limit** JMeter samplers execution rate to desired value, it won't kick off any extra threads if the current throughput is lower than expected. You can consider switching to [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin) combination, they're capable of it.
3. JMeter itself needs to be able to send requests fast enough so make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html). If this is not sufficient you will have to go for the [distributed testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)

Comment: First of all try increasing the number of threads? Thread not constraint. All i need is to publish message with 800 messages per second for 17 seconds